# How to use fields of a flag instead of only toggling the flag?

Tags: 7, entities, flags

I have created a flag (using the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module) called `status` and a field to it and named it `remarks`. Now, how do I let users to flag other users and fill in the remarks field for that particular flag.

All I am able to do is toggle the flag.

I couldn't find any documentation on it and the complimentary module of flag called [flagging form](http://www.drupal.org/project/flagging_form) is obsolete.

When a user flags another user, I want a pop-up to appear asking them for remarks before flagging the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When configuring flag(s) (using the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module), you can indeed attach fields to them. However when doing so, make sure to also be aware about (and do) what is described in [Attaching fields to flags](https://www.drupal.org/node/917576), i.e.:

> By default, Flags use the "JavaScript toggle" link-type. While this allows entities to be flagged without reloading the page, users cannot set any field values with the Flag. In order for users to set a Flag's field values, you must use the "Form" link type.
>
> Navigate to `Administration > Structure > Flags` page. Click the Edit link for the Flag. Scroll down to the Display Options box and select the Confirmation Form radio button.

Comment: thanks. however there is an ajax error (HTTP Result Code 200) now where it should be the dialog box. I used dialog and flagging form module alongside. Is that the cause?

Comment: I think I will use javascript to produce that dialog, and remove that module.